# Account merged, now cannot login to SE chat

Tags: support, status-completed, chat, user-accounts, merge

I am not sure if this is the right place to post this inquiry.

In AU, I have an *old account* with only 1 rep which I have used for about a week. I forgot the password for that account so I then created a new account (this account) which I have been using for almost a month now.

My old account was *flagged to be merged* with this account. Now SE or so I think, does not allow me to talk in any SE Network chat saying that I *need at least 20 rep* to talk in chat.

Does this mean that in Ask Ubuntu I have 600+ rep but on SE, I only have 1 rep (which was my old account's rep)? What should I do for SE to recognize my user profile (credentials) from AU?

On AU, this is my user profile:

[image]

On SE Chat, this is my user profile:
[image]

Every time, I click on my username (circled above) from the SE Chat page, it leads to a *Page Not Found* on AU site.

Also, on the SE Chat page, it seems that I am able to get into any room that I click on, in fact it appears that I am in a room, the only problem is I can't talk (send a message) into the room.

Comment: I'll see what I can do.

Comment: Working on it (/cc @jrg)

Comment: Should work now, can you confirm?

Comment: Yes, it is working now. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

More details: You have multiple chat.SE accounts.

http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/43118/mspeachy

http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/41794/mspeachy

Both link to the correct Ask Ubuntu profile, however the first chat account doesn't refresh from the parent correctly. Theoretically, you should be able to log in right now and be fine, however I'm going to ping a developer about this.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, you are right, two accounts. The first chat.SE account is my current account, and the second was my old account. Whenever I click *chat* from my AU page, it uses the second account to login to SE chat, which does not allow me to talk though.